# Solution of $(z+a) \rho'(z) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This question is related to [another one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444111/bernoullis-principle-for-a-liquid-with-non-uniform-density) (asked by myself) on the Physics forum.

The "more mathematical" part of the question requires the solution of the following differential equation:

$$(z+a) \rho'(z) = 0,$$

where $a$ is a real number and $\rho$ is a real function of $z$.

To me, it seems quite obvious that $\rho(z) = \rho$ represents all the possible solution to this kind of problem. Indeed, $(z+a) \rho'(z)$ must be $0$ for all values of $z$, and then $\rho'(z) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $z\in (-\infty,-a)\cup (-a,+\infty)$ we have $\rho'(z)=0$. Hence 
$$\rho(z)=\begin{cases}\rho_1 & z<-a\\ 
\rho_2 & z>-a\end{cases}\qquad \rho_1,\rho_2\in \mathbb{R} $$
On the other hand $\rho(z)$ is assumed to be differentiable and hence continuous. Therefore $\rho_1=\rho(-a)=\rho_2$ and $\rho(z)$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1 wow, very nice question!!! Is this class of solutions the only one possible?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes. If $\rho'(z)\equiv 0$ on some connected domain $\Omega$, then $\rho(z)$ must be constant on $\Omega$. Since $(-\infty,-a)$ and $(-a,\infty)$ are two disjoint connected domains, $\rho(z)$ must be constant on each of them (but not necessarily the same constant).